# Help examining predicted probabilities from nested logistic models

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, conditional-probability

I am having trouble explaining a recent finding to myself.  I'm not sure if I'm asking a redundant question, but here is my situation:

1) Suppose I want to model the estimated probability of some outcome in a logistic model, then compare the estimated probabilities with a **second set** of estimated probabilities from a **second logistic model**.  I'm doing this in R, and below is a "toy" example using the `mtcars` dataset.  In this example, imagine that I want to summarise the average probability that a car has `vs = 1` based on its `carb`:

`library(tidyverse)`

`#Let's use a simple model`

`fit1 <- glm(vs ~ as.factor(carb), family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mtcars)`

I can compute the average probability for each level of `carb` as follows:

`#Yes, I realize that all cars with a given carb will have the same estimate, so taking the mean is a bit pointless`

`cbind.data.frame(mtcars, pred = predict(fit1, type = "response")) %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  summarise(mean(pred))`

`# A tibble: 6 x 2
      carb   mean(pred)
      <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1        1.000

2     2        0.500

3     3        0.00000000322
4     4        0.200

5     6        0.00000000318
6     8        0.00000000318`

So far so good.  These results are a bit weird, but whatever.  (They are easy to interpret, at least)
Now I want to fit a more complex model, incorporating a new predictor (`mpg`) that should help me get an estimate of the probability *after adjusting for MPG.*

`fit2 <- glm(vs ~ as.factor(carb) + mpg, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mtcars)`

`cbind.data.frame(mtcars, pred = predict(fit2, type = "response")) %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  summarise(mean(pred))`

`# A tibble: 6 x 2
      carb   mean(pred)
      <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1        1.000

2     2        0.500

3     3        0.00000000322
4     4        0.200

5     6        0.00000000318
6     8        0.00000000318`

What I can't figure out is: **why are the estimates exactly the same?**  Surely `mpg` must have *some* predictive value that assists our estimate. Can anyone help explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

To take an example, of the $10$ cars with $4$ carburetors, $2$ (both Mercedes) have their cylinders arranged straight (`vs=1`) and $8$ in a V (`vs=0`).

Your first model therefore predicts that each car with $4$ carburetors has a probability of $0.2$ of having cylinders arranged straight, and it obviously cannot do better than this

Your second model takes into account `mpg` to change the predictions for different cars and each car now has a different predicted probability, but it still gives the average probability of $0.2$ for cars with $4$ carburetors of having cylinders arranged straight, and this makes intuitive sense. Note that the predicted probabilities for the $2$ Mercedes $4$ carburetors with both rise, and the average for the non-Mercedes with $4$ carburetors fall, so in a sense these predictions are *better*